# ASP.NET MVC MEMBERSHIP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership

I have just created a user in ASP.NET MVC ,and i want  to insert him into Membership table. How can i do that? , because i can`t insert into Membership_Users
thanks

Comment: If you added this user using the default registration control provided in new MVC projects, then the user has already been added to the aspnet_users table. If you are not sure where this database is, look at the SQL connection strings in your web.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ASP.NET web site administration tools

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Site_Administration_Tool

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx

Comment: Yes i`m using membership provider with all the necesaire settings in web.config,but it still doesn`t work :((

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the membership provider.

1) Set it in Web.Config
2) Use it in you code

You can see this article : http://odetocode.com/articles/427.aspx